# can not find module "@angular/material"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 2. When I'm trying to import "@angular/material" i'm getting error for this. I'm importing packages like:

```
import {MdDialog} from "@angular/material";
import {MdDialogRef} from "@angular/material";
```

My tsconfig.json file like:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "",
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
"mapRoot": "./",
"module": "es6",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
]
}
}
```

My package.json code:

```
{
 "name": "rmc-temporary",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "license": "MIT",
 "angular-cli": {},
 "scripts": {
   "start": "ng serve",
   "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
   "test": "ng test",
   "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
   "e2e": "protractor"
 },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
 "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
 "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
 "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
 "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
 "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
 "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
 "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
 "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
 "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
 "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
 "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
 "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
 "karma": "1.2.0",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
 "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
 "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
 "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
 "protractor": "4.0.9",
 "ts-node": "1.2.1",
 "tslint": "3.13.0",
 "typescript": "~2.0.3",
 "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
}
}
```

Comment: For some reason you have no `@angular/material` in your `package.json`. That could be the problem.

Comment: I tried to add @angular/material in package.json file, but still getting error.

Comment: Did you do an `npm install` in cmd after adding `@angular/material`?

Comment: I added "@angular/material":"2.2.1" in package.json, and then I fired "npm install" command. After fired this command I got first error like this "npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600"

Comment: The latest version is 2.0.0-alpha.11-3."@angular/material": "2.0.0-alpha.11-3",

Comment: I did this import: **import { MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatSortModule, MatTableModule, MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';** I'm getting an error in this line: ** '@angular/material'**. How can i solve?

Comment: I got. Now is working in my project. I reinstaled and worked. Yesterday i tried to install this way: **npm install g @angular/material --save** and didn't work. Today i removed **g** and i got to work.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Follow these steps to begin using Angular Material.

**Step 1: Install Angular Material**

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

**Step 2: Animations**

Some Material components depend on the Angular animations module in order to be able to do more advanced transitions. If you want these animations to work in your app, you have to install the `@angular/animations` module and include the BrowserAnimationsModule in your app.

```
npm install --save @angular/animations
```

Then

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform browser/animations';

@NgModule({
...
  imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

**Step 3: Import the component modules**

Import the NgModule for each component you want to use:

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
...
imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
...
 })
 export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

be sure to import the Angular Material modules after Angular's BrowserModule, as the import order matters for NgModules

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {MdCardModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        MdCardModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Step 4: Include a theme**

Including a theme is required to apply all of the core and theme styles to your application.

To get started with a prebuilt theme, include the following in your app's index.html:

```
<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It may require a parent npm install:
$ npm i @angular/cdk

Comment: which version of material exports mdcardmodule ?
I need version of material. can you Please mention in npm install command ?

Comment: slight correction:  import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

Answer (score 14):

That's what solved this problem for me.

I used:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm install --save @angular/animations
```

but **INSIDE THE APPLICATION'S FOLDER.**

Source:
https://medium.com/@ismapro/first-steps-with-angular-cli-and-angular-material-5a90406e9a4

Comment: Perfect as anyone would have wanted.

Answer (score 5):

- step 1: `npm install @angular/material`
- step 2: `import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";`
- step 3: after import to app module :

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatDialogModule
       ]
```

- step 4: import on component:   `import { MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';`
- step 5: use popup dialog

```
    showPopup(Id){
            this.matDialog.open(PopupComponent, {
                disableClose: true,
                width: "1200px",
                data: {
                  Title: "im vuong le - dev VietNam",
                  sepId:Id,
                  Message: "test-dialog,
                },
              })
                .afterClosed()
                .subscribe((result) => {
                  if (result == "Yes") {
                    
                  }
                });
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156815/1289713), and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.

Answer (score 4):

Change to,

`import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material'`;

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/eCrgAM20NC0GGlJDrxE5?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried to import like above statement. Its not working for me.

Comment: @ritesh what is the issue?

Comment: It is unable to find the '@angular/material'

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: How come this has been marked an Answer where angular team made an announced in 2016 that material component is not yet ready. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181745/cannot-find-module-angular2-material-material another link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4612

Comment: I have a walkthrough for these issues. Have a look at: http://www.heavyweightsoftware.com/blog/how-to-use-tabs-with-angular-5/

Answer (score 3):

I followed each of the suggestions here (I'm using Angular 7), but nothing worked.  My app refused to acknowledge that @angular/material existed, so it showed an error on this line:

```
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Even though I was using the `--save` parameter to add Angular Material to my project:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

...it refused to add anything to my "`package.json`" file.

I even tried deleting the `package-lock.json` file, as some articles suggest that this causes problems, but this had no effect.

To fix this issue, I had to *manually* add these two lines to my "`package.json`" file.

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "@angular/material": "~7.2.2",
        "@angular/cdk": "~7.2.2",
        ...
```

What I can't tell is whether this is an issue related to using Angular 7, or if it's been around for years....

Answer (score 1):

Found this post: "Breaking changes" in angular 9. All modules must be imported separately. Also a fine module available there, thanks to @jeff-gilliland:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60111086/824622

Answer (score 1):

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `[ng add @angular/material][1]` and yes to add animation and add to environment. You can also select an Angular Material Theme. This single command will add all dependencies and declarations required.
Refer [Angular Material Guide Getting Started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Non of these answers works for me. Since I have previous experiences with not working node modules when I am working with reactjs I have removed my node_modules folder and do a `npm install` again. Then instead of using `import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material'` I have import module `import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'` like this. This works for me:-).

Answer (score -3):

Please check [Angular Getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) :)

1. Install Angular Material and Angular CDK
2. Animations - if you need
3. Import the component modules

and enjoy the `{{Angular}}`