# Can't use material tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I was excited to find about the material tabs stuff at https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTab and was excited to use it in my project.

I added the import as suggested and it wasn't working. I found: [can not find module "@angular/material"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140187/can-not-find-module-angular-material) and imported the stuff and got the import working on my maintab component.

But the mat-tab links are still not working. So here's my maintab.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maintab',
  templateUrl: './maintab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maintab.component.css']
})
export class MaintabComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And here's my maintab.component.html

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="One">
    <h1>Some tab content</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Two">
    <h1>Some more tab content</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I'm still getting these type of errors:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<mat-tab-group>
  [ERROR ->]<mat-tab label="One">
    <h1>Some tab content</h1>
    <p>...</p>
"): ng:///AppModule/MaintabComponent.html@1:2
'mat-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <p>...</p>
  </mat-tab>
```

I just don't know what to do next.

Comment: Figured all of this out. Wrote http://www.heavyweightsoftware.com/blog/how-to-use-tabs-with-angular-5/ with a walkthrough to save future people problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're importing a module into a component. You need to import the `MatTabsModule` into your `AppModule`, and also include it as a provider. As long as your `MaintabComponent` is declared in your App module this will work.

If your `MaintabComponent` isn't declared in your `AppModule` you need to import the `MatTabsModule` and provide in the module where it is declared instead of the `AppModule`.

(If you're still having trouble please include code for your module that this component is declared in for further help)

Comment: You don't have to add the module as a provider.

Comment: I ran into several issues and finally figured it out. I wrote an article: http://www.heavyweightsoftware.com/blog/how-to-use-tabs-with-angular-5/ to walk someone through this process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was getting errors because MatTabModule was in node_modules
To solve this, Go to command prompt and type
`npm install --save @angular/cdk @angular/material`

Answer (score 0):

For me I added `MatTabsModule` into `exports` array instead of `imports` then it worked.